# ORMLite TimeStamp returning Date 2017-01-06 12:50:06.0 want to remove .0 from end

Tags: java, android, orm, ormlite, query-builder

I am trying to return the date from ORM lite query builder 
using Timestamp but 
it is returning  -> 2017-01-06 12:50:06.0 (I WANT TO REMOVE  .0 FROM THE END)

```
getReportBy(String fromDate, String toDate, List<Long> applicationIds) throws SQLException{
    return dao().queryBuilder().orderBy(CREATED_AT, false).where()
       .between(CREATED_AT, Timestamp.valueOf(fromDate + " 00:00:01"),
               Timestamp.valueOf(toDate + " 23:59:59"))
       .and().in(APPLICATION_ID, applicationIds)
       .and().ne("status","REGENERATE_OTP").query();
```

THANKS

Comment: Can you show your entity and the Ormlite annotations you are currently using?

Comment: in the entity it is String but in the DB it Timestamp datatype ... when it returns it give String and when it takes it takes a String

Answer (score 0):

Just Added a simple String manipulation method and solved the problem ... Thanks all

Here is the small code patch

```
report.setCreatedAt(report.getCreatedAt().replace(".0",""));
```